# Step-in and step-out in LINQ expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a group of radiobuttons that are placed in their own containers for the purpose of CSS styling. They look a little like this:

```
<div id="radiobuttonscontainer" runat="server">
    <div class="buttoncontainer">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" GroupName="rbgroup"/>
    </div>
    <div class="buttoncontainer">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" GroupName="rbgroup"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to group these buttons and find which one is selected. This would seem to be a logical function of `GroupName`, but it is not.

If they were all in a single `<div>` container, I could cycle through them with a simple LINQ query:

```
var checkedButton = radiobuttonscontainer.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                  .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Can I adapt this expression to step in and out of `buttoncontainer` divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using HTML controls, I changed the `buttoncontainer` div elements to `asp:Panel` elements instead, because these render as `div` elements in the final HTML whilst allowing me to treat them as .NET objects. I could then perform a specific nested LINQ query, like so:

`RadioButton selected = radiobuttonscontainer.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                                .SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
                                        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);`

The first iteration (`radiobuttonscontainer.Controls.OfType<Panel>()`) returns all of the `Panel` objects in the container, but with the addition of `.SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())`, that selection is refined to any `RadioButton` objects in the first selection (I.E. "stepping in and out" of the `Panels`). This is because I specifically identify those controls with the parameters for `SelectMany` with `c => c.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()`.

Since my design only allows for one `RadioButton` element in each panel, this isn't a problem, but if I had multiple `RadioButton` elements, I might have to refine the parameter to be more specific depending on the use-case.

The final part (`.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked)`) further refines the selection, returning the first `RadioButton` object that is checked. Since, in this case, only one `RadioButton` can ever be selected, this suffices and returns only a single object. If more than one `RadioButton` could be checked, I would need to use another `SelectMany` expression instead of `FirstOrDefault`, and the returned object would be a list or array of `RadioButton` objects.

Many thanks to [Tom W](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/313414) and [milleniumbug](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1012936) in the C# chat for helping out.